# Can't code in existing android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I added a new Android project from existing code that I wrote 1 year ago. (API 17, ADT 2.2...)

I successfully added the application in my new ADT 2.3...

I can run the application, but i am getting a few errors that I need to fix.

When I add me new code (tried even with easy message changes) I get no response.

It is like my project doesn't read my new code and just runs the existing code from the application that I added.

Please give me some tips how to fix this. It is so annoying.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to include all of the errors you're getting if you want helpful feedback.  Otherwise, create a new project and copy-paste your code in.

Answer (score 0):

Without the errors I can't be very sure, but I have had this happen on a number of different times. To save a lot of headaches for yourself, create a new project instead of creating a new one with old code. Refactor your code piece by piece as you pull your code into the new project.